# How to prevent RestHighLevelClient from connecting to elasticsearch while creating a bean for test

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch, resthighlevelclient

I have a configuration class that creates `RestHighLevelClient` and `ElasticsearchOperations`, they work very well when I start the application. Unfortunately, I am facing an issue with tests.

My configuration class:

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.XXX.search")
@Configuration
@EnableElasticsearchRepositories(basePackages = "com.XXX.search.index.repository")
public class RestHighLevelClientConfiguration {

    @Value("${elasticsearch.host:localhost}")
    private String host;

    @Value("${elasticsearch.port:9201}")
    private Integer port;

    @Bean
    public ElasticsearchOperations elasticsearchTemplate() {
        return new ElasticsearchRestTemplate(client());
    }

    @Bean
    RestHighLevelClient client() {
        final RestClientBuilder builder = RestClient.builder(new HttpHost(host, port)).setRequestConfigCallback(new RestClientBuilder.RequestConfigCallback() {
                @Override
                public RequestConfig.Builder customizeRequestConfig(RequestConfig.Builder requestConfigBuilder) {
                    return requestConfigBuilder.setConnectTimeout(5000).setSocketTimeout(60000);
                }
            });

        return new RestHighLevelClient(builder);
    }
}
```

This is a test class that is failing:

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = Application.class)
@TestPropertySource(locations = "classpath:test.properties")
public class ApplicationTest {
    
    @Test
    public void applicationContextLoads() {
        // nothing to add here.
    }
}
```

Maven dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
        <artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
        <version>7.12.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-elasticsearch</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

When I run the above test, I am getting the following exception:

```
        Caused by: org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: Connection refused; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Connection refused
        at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.ElasticsearchExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ElasticsearchExceptionTranslator.java:75)
        at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.ElasticsearchRestTemplate.translateException(ElasticsearchRestTemplate.java:402)
        at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.ElasticsearchRestTemplate.execute(ElasticsearchRestTemplate.java:385)
        at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.DefaultIndexOperations.doExists(DefaultIndexOperations.java:107)
        at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.AbstractDefaultIndexOperations.exists(AbstractDefaultIndexOperations.java:141)
        at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.support.SimpleElasticsearchRepository.<init>(SimpleElasticsearchRepository.java:93)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:208)
        ... 95 common frames omitted
        Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Connection refused
        at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.ElasticsearchRestTemplate.translateException(ElasticsearchRestTemplate.java:400)
        ... 104 common frames omitted
        Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
        at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient.extractAndWrapCause(RestClient.java:880)
        at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient.performRequest(RestClient.java:283)
        at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient.performRequest(RestClient.java:270)
        at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.internalPerformRequest(RestHighLevelClient.java:1654)
        at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.performRequest(RestHighLevelClient.java:1639)
        at org.elasticsearch.client.IndicesClient.exists(IndicesClient.java:963)
        at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.DefaultIndexOperations.lambda$doExists$2(DefaultIndexOperations.java:107)
        at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.ElasticsearchRestTemplate.execute(ElasticsearchRestTemplate.java:383)
        ... 103 common frames omitted
        Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:717)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.DefaultConnectingIOReactor.processEvent(DefaultConnectingIOReactor.java:174)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.DefaultConnectingIOReactor.processEvents(DefaultConnectingIOReactor.java:148)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.execute(AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.java:351)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.conn.PoolingNHttpClientConnectionManager.execute(PoolingNHttpClientConnectionManager.java:221)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.CloseableHttpAsyncClientBase$1.run(CloseableHttpAsyncClientBase.java:64)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I would appreciate any help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The `ElasticsearchOperations` implementations and the client do not connect automatically to the Elasticsearch cluster.

What is automatically connecting are `ElasticsearchRepository` instances on creation when the entity they are defined for have the `createIndex` property set to true - which is the default value.

So you should exclude repositories from your test setup if you do not need them - or you could provide an Elasticsearch for testing, for example by using  [TestContainers](https://www.testcontainers.org/).

Comment: Thanks, I have set `createIndex = false` in `@Document` annotation and tests have not failed. I think it is fine for this case to skip creation of the document mapping automatically.

Comment: do you know also how I can exclude repositories from my test setup?

Comment: depends on what you are testing. If you for example are testing a controller that has a repository injected, then you'll have to mock that repository to prevent the repository instance from being created.